# MS SQL Server to Oracle script translation

Tags: sql-server, oracle, plsql, database-migration

I wrote a script in SQL Server and now it looks like I need to use it in Oracle. I tried for some time now and I wasn't able to achieve anything with my tries other than constantly receiving some errors.
Could someone please advise me how to amend the following script so it can work in Oracle?

```
DECLARE @oid VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @toids TABLE (oid VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @toids (oid) SELECT oid FROM awftask WHERE oid in (SELECT oid 
FROM agltransactmap)



WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @toids WHERE oid IS NOT NULL) > 0
BEGIN
SET @oid = (SELECT TOP 1 oid FROM @toids); 

INSERT INTO awftaskfin (some staff) FROM awftask
WHERE oid in (@oid);
```

here are some other inserts and deletes and then the scripts end:

```
END
```

I would really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: SQL Developer, Tools > Migrations > Scratch Editor. SQL Dev does have a feature that can help translate T-SQL to PL/SQL - but you need to first figure out what the BEST way to do something in Oracle is per your needs. A direct 1:1 translation may work, but may not be the way to go.

Comment: What have you tried and what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TYPE StringList IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);
/

DECLARE
  toid StringList;
BEGIN
  SELECT oid
  BULK COLLECT INTO toid
  FROM   awftask
  WHERE  oid IN ( SELECT oid FROM agltransactmap );

  FOR i IN 1 .. toid.COUNT LOOP
    INSERT INTO awftaskfin (some staff) VALUES ( toid(i) );
    -- here are some other inserts and deletes
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```